# My app is not able to receive data if it is in background and if app is reopened by any other application in Android

Tags: android

> I want to opened my application from another application with passing some data to my app.
>   If my app is not running on background and if it is opened by other application then i am able to received data which will passed by other app.
>   I am trying to get data to receive in `onResume()` function of my `MainActivity` but it will not work.
>   Code that i written to Send Data on click of button is:

```
PackageManager pmn = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pmn.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.myAppPackage");          
String some_str = "Hello World";
intent.putExtra("some_str", some_str);
startActivity(intent);
```

> My code in onResume is:

```
@Override
       public void onResume() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           super.onResume();
           Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
           String str = null;
           if(bundle != null && bundle.getString("some_str") != null){
               str = bundle.getString("some_str");
           }
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "some_str :: "+str , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
```

> But it is showing `null` value in `Toast`.

Comment: Make sure you'r passing the key `some_str` same as you retrieve.

Comment: @Piyush, please check my edited question also contains code that pass some_str to my application

Comment: Try to get data in `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` method which is override method and you can use in your activity instead of retrieve data in `onResume()` method.

Comment: @Piyush thank you, using onNewIntent() function i am able to receive data

Comment: Yes I know  :) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just write onResume

```
if(bundle != null && bundle.getString("some_str") != null){
        String some_str =  bundle.getString("some_str");
        //str= this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("some_str");


    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "some_str :: "+some_str , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: In the above code how can i fetch bundle value, if you see in my question the code that i written to assign bundle is Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

Comment: It is working for me..like String buttnd =  bundle.getString("some_str");